# JDBC Error "Lost Connection" during very large select statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Hi and thanks for any help in advance.

I am trying to run a very large query on a AWS MYSQL RDS from JDBC (in a Java program that is hosted on and AWS EC2 Instance). The Query returns ~130mil rows and I have successfully ran queries using the same program that return ~20mil rows and write them out to a text file.

About 15 minutes into the query I get a lost connection error that points back to this part of the code:

```
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Is there a setting on MYSQL or in JDBC that could be timing this connection out, or is there something else I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run this inside a container like tomcat or jboss or is it standalone code Directly dealing with jdbc? 
In case of container having connection pools you have timeouts to be configured. 
On the other hand: what's the sense of extracting that amount of data?

Comment: It is standalone code directly dealing with JDBC. I need to extract this much data because it is a record linkage program that needs to consider the entire universe (this table).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int). Take onto account your jdbc driver implementation which can have a default which is not endless.  Also check on your database if there is a connection timeout set.  Which db vendor is it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your [jdbc settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), maybe connection closed by timeout.